# cbind arguments in large dataframe

Tags: r, subtotal

I have searched unsuccessfully for several days for an answer to this question: I have a dataframe with 279 columns and want to generate subtotals using aggregate(), or indeed, anything suitable. Here is a subset:

```
     LGA            off.cat                          sub.cat       Jan1995   Feb1995
    1 Albury        Homicide                              Murder *       0       0
    2 Albury        Homicide                      Attempted murder       0       0
    3 Albury        Homicide          Murder accessory, conspiracy       0       0
    4 Albury        Homicide                        Manslaughter *       0       0
    5 Albury         Assault     Domestic violence related assault       7       7
    6 Albury         Assault Non-domestic violence related assault      29      20
    7 Albury         Assault                        Assault Police      12       3
    8 Albury Sexual offences                        Sexual assault       4       3
```

The full dataframe contains dozens of LGA values, and many more date columns. I would like to obtain subtotals for each unique LGA value grouped by unique values of off.cat and sub.cat, summed over all dates. I tried using cbind in aggregate, but found no way to generate the 276 date column names that would not cause errors. Explicit column names worked fine. Apologies for the lack of clarity in the earlier post, and thanks to those who valiantly tried to interpret my meaning.

Comment: Hello on SO. Can you provide sample of data (eg. using `head`) and code for working example to show us what is wrong?

Comment: What are you using `cbind` for in your `aggregate`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you're referring to the formula interface to `aggregate` like `aggregate(cbind(mpg,cyl,disp) ~ gear, data=mtcars, FUN=sum)`. If so, I'd just use the boring alternative method - `aggregate(mtcars[c("mpg","cyl","disp")], mtcars["gear"], FUN=sum)` - which should be much more easily programmed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you may be successful using the formula syntax of `aggregate`. Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(group = letters[1:5],
                 x = 1:5,
                 y = 6:10,
                 z = 11:15)

  group x  y  z
1     a 1  6 11
2     b 2  7 12
3     c 3  8 13
4     d 4  9 14
5     e 5 10 15
```

We now `sum` all three variables `x`, `y` and `z` by the levels of `group`, using `setdiff` to get a vector of column names except `group`, and pasting them together to use in `as.formula`:

```
aggregate(as.formula(paste(paste(setdiff(names(df), c("group")), collapse = "+"), "~ group")), data = df, sum)

  group x + y + z
1     a        18
2     b        21
3     c        24
4     d        27
5     e        30
```

Hope this helps.